# Deep nest a value into a hash given a path array

Tags: ruby, associative-array

I am looking for a concise way to set the value into a hash deep given a list of key accessors.

```
path = [:mountain, :river, :tree]
hash = {}
deep_nest(hash, path, 23)
=> { mountain: { river: { tree: 23 } } }
```

I get it working with the following code

```
deep = path.inject(hash) do |hash, field|
  if hash.key?(field)
    hash[field]
  else
    hash[field] = {}
  end
end

deep[path.last] = 23
```

Is there a shorter way? Normally default initialization works neatly on hashes, but this only works for the first, level, maybe this could be done more dynamically.

Comment: Is your hash initially empty?

Comment: @ArupRakshit No, unfortunately not necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether this meets the definition of concise, but one way to solve this would be to construct the full path with value as a hash, and deep-merge it with the original hash, allowing for the original hash being non-empty.

```
path = [:mountain, :river, :tree]
hash = {:mountain=>{:river=>{:tree=>66}, :house=>:red}}
hash.merge!((path + [23]).reverse.reduce { |s,e| { e => s } }) { |k,o,n| o.merge(n) }
# => {:mountain=>{:river=>{:tree=>23}, :house=>:red}}
```

Note I use `path + [23]` rather than `path << 23` to avoid modifying `path`, and `merge!` rather than `merge` to modify `hash`.

An explanation of the stages (working outwards):

- `(path + [23]).reverse.reduce { |s,e| { e => s } }` :
  create a hash of the path with value
- `hash.merge!( ... ) { |k,o,n| o.merge(n) }` :
  deep-merge the hash with the merge strategy new-value-merges-onto-old-value

(This question is spookily similar to https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4417754 , although not identical.)

Comment: That's a great answer. The question on the Ruby Forum, that's weird, it is definitely not me, I guess someone wanted to answer this question here so he/she asked somewhere else? ;)

Comment: @GuaranaJoe, Thank you—glad I could help. :) Maybe so; I think your question was posted first, although I only came across it afterwards. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the hash initialization:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc)
path[0..-1].inject(hash) { |hash, key| hash[key] }[path.last] = 23
```

With `&h.default_proc` a new proc instance is assigned every time a new key is hit. This way an infinite loop is created. By making  use of `default_proc` it works for arbitrary depths as opposed to

```
Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(self) }
```

which only works for two levels, because it references the same proc instance.